# Android: Error accessing directory tree URI from Intent data

Tags: java, android, file, android-intent

I am new to Android development and currently working on an app that requires accessing JSON data from text files located in the device's "Documents" directory. I have test device which runs Android 13. To enable the functionality, I am using Storage Access Framework to open file explorer and select the directory. However, I am unable to proceed with the directory URI.

```java
public void openDirectory(Uri uriToLoad) {
        // Choose a directory using the system's file picker.
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
        intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, uriToLoad);
        startActivityForResult(intent, DOCUMENTS_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

```java
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == DOCUMENTS_REQUEST_CODE
                && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // The result data contains a URI for the document or directory that
            // the user selected.
            Uri uri = null;

            if (data != null) {
                Uri directoryUri = data.getData();
                Log.i("uri path", directoryUri.getPath());
                Log.i("uri string value", String.valueOf(directoryUri));
                
               accessFilesInDirectory(directoryUri);

            }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

The values logged are

```
uri path: /tree/primary:Documents/SMART/Fall_data
uri string value: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADocuments%2FSMART%2FFall_data
```

Is the URI in correct format?
I am unable to figure the right way to implement accessFilesInDirectory().

I have tried

```java
              File directory = new File(String.valueOf(directoryUri));
              File[] files = directory.listFiles();
              for (File file : files) {
                   try {
                        Log.i("LOAD FILES:", "file name: ". concat(file.getName()));
                        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                        String line;
                        StringBuilder string
                        .
                        .
                        .
```

It gave following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADocuments%2FSMART%2FFall_data
```

```java
// Get a ContentResolver instance
                ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

                // Query for files in the specified directory
                String[] projection = new String[]{DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID, DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME};
                String selection = DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_MIME_TYPE + " = ?";
                String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"application/json"};

                Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(directoryUri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
```

It gave following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Uri content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADocuments%2FSMART%2FFall_data
```

Please provide the correct way to this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of other answers of other stackoverflow questions, I was able to write this working code by using DocumentFile.

```java
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == DOCUMENTS_REQUEST_CODE
                && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            if (data != null) {
                Uri directoryUri = data.getData();
                ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

                Gson gson = new Gson();

                DocumentFile directory = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, directoryUri);
                assert directory != null;
                Log.i("directory files length", String.valueOf(directory.listFiles().length));
                for (DocumentFile documentFile : directory.listFiles()) {
                    Log.i("documentFile name ", documentFile.getName());
                    try {
                        InputStream inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(documentFile.getUri());
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                        // logic to read data

                    } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).